# pushing viewcontroller from bottom, sometimes occurs from side

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to push my viewcontroller from the bottom using this code.

However, Sometimes, this is not successful and it ends up pushing the default way which is from the side.

here is my code:

```
let transition = CATransition()
                transition.type = kCATransitionPush
                transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
                self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatController, animated: false)
```

am I missing something here?

Comment: Why not use present controller rather than pushing.

Comment: Because i need to keep it in the navigation stack

Comment: you did that right, may be a glitch in animation is responsible for that unexpected behaviour

Comment: You are hacking internal implementation which is something you should not be doing. Random graphical problems are to be expected.

Comment: @slimboy one try you can give is just write this line and give a duration 0.25 `transition.duration = 0.25` and try to replicate the issue. Check

Comment: I think your right rajan thanks